# If $AB=BA$ and $AB$ is diagonal are $A$ and $B$ both diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm stuck with this problem. If $AB=BA$ and $AB$ is diagonal are $A$ and $B$ both diagonal?

Comment: For a non-invertible example, you can take $A$ to be a non-zero matrix s.t. $A^2=0$.  Then take $B=A$.  So $AB=BA=0$, but a non-zero nilpotent matrix can never be diagonal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint :** think about permutations.

Further informations about the hint : think about the matrix representation given by the linear transformation $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(e_1)=e_2$ and $f(e_2)=e_1$.

**More general answer**

As noted by Enkidu in the comments, all non diagonal invertible matrices will also do. Since $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A =I$. But you do not need invertibility (add a line and a column of zero to any invertible matrix for example).

Comment: I don't follow how that relates to my question. I'm sorry...

Comment: Or just invertible matrices: $AA^{-1}=id=A{-1}A $ is clearly diagonal, but they for sure do not need to be diagonalizable, as we only need invertibility

Comment: Permutations matrices are indeed not the only ones achieving the OP's assertion. @Enkidu

Comment: Exactly, just wanted to throw in a general example, as before it was just stating: Think about permutations, at least when I wrote that comment.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, both of you!

Comment: Small side note that might explain where your thought might come fram, if A and B commute and are diagonalizable, you can simultaneously diagonalize them , i.e. You find a basis where BOTH are diagonal, maybe you confused that

Comment: Yes I think that was my confusion. Thanks again