# If $A,B$ are invertible commuting $2\times 2$ matrices, and $AB$ is diagonal but not multiple of the identity. Are A,B both diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

The problem is as in the title. I think the answer is yes.

There is a similar question here: [If $AB=BA$ and $AB$ is diagonal are $A$ and $B$ both diagonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666255/if-ab-ba-and-ab-is-diagonal-are-a-and-b-both-diagonal)

But the counterexamples are either non-invertible, or $AB=I$.

Comment: $AB=4I$ may lead to a contradiction similar to $AB=I.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I see, perhaps I should enforce $AB$ to not be a multiple of the identity since then we can avoid any inverse shenanigans. I will add that in.

Comment: I perhaps should point out Mathematica says that this is indeed true.

Comment: Note that $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$ with $a\ne d$ commutes with $B$ only if $B=\begin{pmatrix}a'&0\\0&d'\end{pmatrix}$. And  $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ commutes with $B$ only if $B=\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\0&a'\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: If $A$ commutes with $B$ then $A$ and $B$ commute with $AB.$

Comment: Let $A$ be any non-diagonal invertible matrix and $B$ be $A^{-1}C$ for any invertible diagonal matrix $C$ that commutes with $A$ but is not a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are (invertible) commuting $n \times n$ matrices and $AB$ is diagonal with distinct entries, then $A$ and $B$ are both diagonal. Conversely, $AB$ must of course be diagonal and if it has repeated entries then taking $A$ to be a Jordan block on those entries ("block" if those entries are not consecutive) gives a counterexample.

To see this, note that if $A$ and $B$ commute then $A$ commutes with $AB$, so $A(AB) v = AB (Av)$. Taking $v = e_i$ (the $i$th unit vector) we get $AB(A e_i) = \lambda_i (Ae_i)$ (with $\lambda_i$ the $i$th entry on the diagonal of $AB$). So $Ae_i$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (or $0$ if $A$ is not assumed to be invertible), and since $AB$ has distinct eigenvalues it must be a multiple of $e_i$. This holds for each $i$, ie $A$ is diagonal.

You can either apply the same argument to $B$, or note that if $AB$ and $A$ are diagonal and $A$ is invertible then so is $B = A^{-1} (AB)$.